# equal border height for all columns in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having 3 columns in a row[image: screen shot of my problem]

i need this border in the middle of Proper Description of goods & Net quantity per package to be extend till the parallel column(Marks and Number of Packages) border height

Comment: You should give your jsfiddle link

Comment: this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Used to** `table` `height:100%;`

```
table{
height:100%;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/2/)***

Comment: ya..its working now... but in print i am getting like this..after using                                                          table{
height:100%;
}                                                                  i am getting like this.....http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/

Comment: Used to td{vertical-align:top;} in your css file

Comment: still i am getting the same in printing...can you rectify me

Comment: if i am using like you said i am having output as ....http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/ ..but i need the output as http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/ ...pls clarify me

Comment: i am having a dynamic page with rows and columns...if i use this height:100%" ..its working the column border extends upto the parallel column border height...but i am getting spaces between each line like this http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/ ...can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a structure like this one:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Marks</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Lorem...</td>
        <td>Lorem...</td>
        <td>Sit...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Name and Address</td>
        <td colspan='2'>Signature and date</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Look at the attribute **colspan** on the second cell in the third row

Answer (score 0):

First put style `height:100%` on `<td>` containing `<table>` as

```
    <td width="63%" rowspan="2" valign="top" 
style="border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;font-size:18px;height:100%">
```

Then, put style `height:inherit` on `<table>` under that `<td>` as

```
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
style="height:inherit">
```

Comment: if i am using like you said i am having output as ....http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/ ..but i need the output as http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/  ...pls clarify me

Comment: i am having a dynamic page with rows and columns...if i use this height:100%" and style="height:inherit"..its working the column border extends upto the parallel column border height...but i am getting spaces between each line like this http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/ ...can you help me

Comment: When I check on the fiddle, there is no style according as I posted. The space between the line is because of many `<br>` tags. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/T2jZC/). This will work well. I've also include `vertical-align:top` to correct the output.

Comment: i am using that break to show you how i am getting the output in my dynamic webpage.. http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/18/ pls check this fiddle..i am using as you said.. i am getting the values of the two columns from response.write...can you rectify me

Comment: So now I think just the problem there is 'middle alignment of text'. Make alignment vertical(I've given the link before). Is there some other problem?

Comment: currently i am getting the output as http://i.stack.imgur.com/eaz88.jpg   but i need to have is  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xj2lc.jpg  dont know why the space comes between the rows..is it possible to reduce...

Comment: I don't know why there is space between the rows. May be your program generate more than one `<br>` tags *it seems your program generate four `<br>` tags, it should generate only one*. Check your code that generate the text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20862/discussion-between-affan-and-vusan)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Introduce Second Table in your code

```
Check Fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/7/