# equal table border height for all columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having 3 columns in a row and my current output is[image: Current output]

and my needed output is ![needed output][2]

![cur o/p][2]

[image: needed]

Comment: please post link off fiddle ...too ..

Comment: current output is    http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/  ....and needed is   http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/

Comment: table border height? please specify more what you want

Comment: my previous fiddle is.. http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/1/ and after using table{ height:100%} i am getting the output as http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/  but my needed output is.... http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/

Comment: You have a fiddle link to the required output? So what are you asking?

Comment: what i am asking is..my column border extends up to the parallel column..but i am getting like this http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/  ...but i need is  http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/

Comment: possible duplicate of [equal border height for all columns in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758390/equal-border-height-for-all-columns-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

you have 4 
 tags between the texts

```
Lorem Ipsum<br><br><br><br> passages, <br><br><br><br>and more recently
```

remove them.

Comment: actually i need to show my output for that i am using that <br>..in my original page...i am getting that breaks even if the lines are dont have <br>

Comment: can you post the js fiddle with that output without the <br>?

Comment: my previous fiddle is.. http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/1/ and after using table{ height:100%} i am getting the output as http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/8/  but my needed output is.... http://jsfiddle.net/6XsKj/12/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [colspan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute to specify how much space each column takes. Also, use the `<style>` tag to set css for elements, instead of putting them inline, which clutters the site.

HTML+CSS:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" padding="2" style="font-size:18px;">

<tbody>

<tr height="46" colspan="3">
<td width="30%">&nbsp;Marks and Number of packages</td>
<td width="50%">&nbsp;Proper Description of goods</td>
<td width="20%">&nbsp;Net quantity per &nbsp;package</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableContent">
<td colspan="1" valign="top">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type </td>
<td colspan="1" valign="top">Lorem Ipsum<br> passages, <br>and more recently</td>
<td colspan="1" valign="top">sit amet,<br> consectetur<br> adipisicing elit, <br>sed do eiusmod tempor</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="50" valign="top" colspan="1">&nbsp;Name and Address of Shipper</td>
<td valign="top" colspan="2">&nbsp;Signature & Date</td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
​
<style type="text/css">
.tableContent td, td{
padding-left:10px;
}
</style>
​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Csr6X/