# equal table border height for all columns in a row

Tags: html, css, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [equal border height for all columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758390/equal-border-height-for-all-columns-in-a-table)

i am having 3 columns in a row my current output is![current output][1]

[image] 
and my needed output is

[image: needed]

Comment: The two tables look the same. What's the differences?

Comment: sorry..done a mistake..check the outputs now

Comment: seems like you are searching for `rowspan` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS: {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

or `<td>` attribute:

```
<td valign="top"></td>
```